# Joomla Get/POST parameters ignoring white space in string

Tags: php, http, joomla, parameters

I am using Joomla 3.4.
And I am using standard Joomla way to GET parameters.
let's assume url contains 
signup?company=ZITO%20MEDIA,%20LP

According Joomla Standard code

```
$config = new JConfig();
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
echo $jinput->get->get('company');
```

The result: ZITOMEDIALP

But if I change the code to standard php code

```
echo $_GET['company'];
```

The result: ZITO MEDIA, LP

I want to use joomla code since I working on joomla project but this is not what I want.

any ideas? and it happens to POST variables as well.

Comment: Try asking your question on [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput), JInput by default applies the "cmd" filter which basically strips off whatever is not a-z.

You should apply the desired filter, e.g. "int", "string", "word", ... with this syntax:

```
$jinput->get('varname', 'default_value', 'filtername');
```

There is also a shorthand method for most of the filters, for example the following two lines of code are equivalent:

```
$jinput->get('varname', 'default_value', 'string');
$jinput->getString('varname', 'default_value');
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
echo $jinput->get->get('company');
```

to

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
echo $jinput->getString('company', 'default_value');
```

use a default value as well in order to be able to handle the case of a missing parameter.